# From the given figure, prove that $\angle KAL = \angle MBN$

Tags: geometry

From the figure below, prove that $\angle KAL = \angle MBN$.
[image]

I only know that $\angle K = \frac{\frown AN - \frown AL}{2}$. Can you give me a hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  Observe that $\angle AKM=\angle ABM=\angle ABN - \angle MBN=\angle ALN -\angle MBN$.

> Thus, $$\angle KAL = \angle ALN-\angle AKL = \angle MBN\,.$$